# Primary Key value in datagrid with ObservableCollection (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

Don't throw stones at me - I am quite new in programming, especially in Entity Framework.

I created a small program, that records some variables to SQL table. For representation of table with record variables I use datagrid, that is bound with `ObservableCollection`. The `Datagrid` looks like this:

[recorded variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNfdM.png)

**Id** is the primary key with seed 1. The problem is how to show actual Id number without querying a SQL table?

I tried this:

```
VariableRecordOCtoShow.Add(new VariableRecord() //VariableRecord is class from entity model
            {
                Value = newVariableRecord.Value,
                Time = newVariableRecord.Time,
                IdVariableAssignment = newVariableRecord.IdVariableAssignment,
                IdUser = newVariableRecord.IdUser
            });
```

But in Id column in datagrid were only zeros.

I tried this: firstly create a database, what is las Id number

```
public int getIdValue()
{
    var query = (from p in context.VariableRecords  
                 orderby p.Id descending           
                 select p).Take(1).Single();       
    return query.Id; 
}
```

Secondly write it do variable:

```
idVariable = getIdValue();
```

Then write it to Id of `ObservableCollection` in (not class of entity model) and increase by one this variable after each record (below is part of writing method):

```
VariableRecordOCtoShow.Add(new VariableRecord() // v tomto velkem radku jenom zapisuju do Observable Collection hodnoty ze vstupu + Id
            {
                Id = idVariable, //fake Id (calculated from query)
                Value = newVariableRecord.Value,
                Time = newVariableRecord.Time,
                IdVariableAssignment = newVariableRecord.IdVariableAssignment,
                IdUser = newVariableRecord.IdUser
            });

            idVariable++;
```

It works, but only in the beginning - when I tested my program overnight, there was some error with performance (some variables didn't write in time) and at final Id from OC and Id from SQL doesn't match.

Can you help me? How can I display *real* primary key value in datagrid without querying while record is running?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is how to show actual Id number without querying a SQL table?

I am not sure about your question

Firstly, why don't you want to query the SQL table?

Secondly, we generally don't show ID field (Identity field) in the view. It's not a good practice.

And still you want to show then you can always query in EF :

```
ObservableCollection<VariableRecords> v = 
      new  ObservableCollection<VariableRecords>(from p in context.VariableRecords
                                                 select c)
```

Also your second approach might create problems in future as identity field ID is not always Max(ID) +1. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

> Reuse of values – For a given identity property with specific seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity values are generated.